# How to add a launcher for Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I reinstalled Anaconda, and then created a virtual environment that I need.

On Anaconda Navigator, several tools are installed and ready to be launched, or ready to be installed (Spyder, VS Code...), but not Jupyter Notebook for this virtual environment.

I installed Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda Prompt and I can use it, but it would be practical to have an icon for Jupyter on Anaconda Navigator, and I don't find how to get this launcher.

Have you an idea ?